In app purchase in ios side not working .?{"error": [Error: An unknown error occurred], "success": false} paymentResult
I have a issue in In-app-purchase ios side .I am getting product from app store
LOG  [{"countryCode": "PAK", "currency": "PKR", "description": "Buy to add amazing features ", "discounts": [], "introductoryPrice": "", "introductoryPriceAsAmountIOS": "", "introductoryPriceNumberOfPeriodsIOS": "", "introductoryPricePaymentModeIOS": "", "introductoryPriceSubscriptionPeriodIOS": "", "localizedPrice": "Rs 12,900", "platform": "ios", "price": "12900", "productId": "Feast_179", "subscriptionPeriodNumberIOS": "1", "subscriptionPeriodUnitIOS": "MONTH", "title": "Feast Premium access", "type": "subs"}]
but when i request Subscription
requestSubscription({
sku: myProducts,
...('offerToken' && {
subscriptionOffers: [
{
sku: myProducts, // as a string
offerToken:
Platform.OS == 'android'
? value[0].subscriptionOfferDetails[0].offerToken
: 'offerToken',
},
],
}),
})
it through error  {"error": [Error: An unknown error occurred], "success": false}
i add all required configuration in xcode
Trying to make this work
